# Updating a mySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to update a mySQL column,

basically I would like to get a specific user in the DB, and then add the number I have to the number in the DB column.

So say for instance user 12345 has 55 points, and I wanna add 25 points to his score, how would I go about updating the points column to reflect 80?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE scoreboard
SET points=points+25
WHERE user=12345
```

Comment: Probably a noob mistake, but I am using PHP to do the update, and I am getting this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user=12345' at line 1"

And here is my code mysql_query("UPDATE scoreboard SET points=points+$points WHERE user=$uid")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Are you sanitizing and validating `$points`? What does it contain?

Comment: I am getting points via $_GET like so $points = $_GET['points'], so no sanitation that I know of.

Comment: I have a users table in my database which contains the userId and points columns.

Comment: "no sanitation that I know of" FIX THIS. It will bite you in the behind eventually.

Comment: My bad, stupid mistake, the $_GET variable wasn't set! It's working now! Thanx alot for the help! function sanitize($hello)
{
 $hello = strip_tags($hello);
 $hello = mysql_real_escape_string($hello);
 return $hello;
}
, would this be ok?

Comment: For the sanitization, sure. Validating that it's an integer will help you catch other problems as well.

Comment: Cool, will implement that! Thanx for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE scores SET
points = points + 25
WHERE id = 12345;
```